# Unit tests for kubernetes controller

Tags: go, kubernetes, autoscaling

I'm trying to write a controller and I'm having a few issues writing tests.

I've used some code from the k8s HPA in my controller and I'm seeing something weird when using the `testrestmapper`.

basically when running this [test](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/c6ebd126a77e75e6f80e1cd59da6b887e783c7c4/pkg/controller/podautoscaler/horizontal_test.go#L852) with a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/7498c14218403c9a713f9e0747f2c6794a0da9c7/pkg/controller/podautoscaler/horizontal.go#L512) I see the mappings are returned.

When I do the same the mappings are not returned.

What magic is happening here?

The following test fails

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/meta/testrestmapper"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/schema"
    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/legacyscheme"
    "testing"
)

func TestT(t *testing.T) {
    mapper := testrestmapper.TestOnlyStaticRESTMapper(legacyscheme.Scheme)

    gk := schema.FromAPIVersionAndKind("apps/v1", "Deployment").GroupKind()
    mapping, err := mapper.RESTMapping(gk)

    assert.NoError(t, err)
    assert.NotNil(t, mapping)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because you are missing an import of `_ "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/apps/install"`.

Without importing this path, there are no API groups or versions registered with the `schema` you are using to obtain the REST mapping.

By importing the path, the API group will be registered, allowing the call to `schema.FromAPIVersionAndKind("apps/v1", "Deployment").GroupKind()` to return a valid GroupKind.